# Error in stored procedure with cursor declare

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a Stored Procedure in mySQL which takes in the users ID, Name and Location from another table at set intervals. If the record does not exist it will create it, however if it does exist and the 'Location' field is different (ID and userName are PK's) then it will update the record with the new location.

Here is the SP so far, and note that this **does not** currently work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `testTransfer` ()
BEGIN

DECLARE myCUR CURSOR FOR SELECT ID, userName, Location FROM usertable;
DECLARE decID int;
DECLARE decName varchar(70);
DECLARE decLocation int;

OPEN myCUR;
FETCH NEXT FROM myCUR INTO decID, decName, decLocation;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0;

INSERT INTO users_log (ID, userName, Location)
VALUES (decID, decName, decLocation)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    ID = decID,
    userName = decName,
    Location = decLocation;
    
FETCH NEXT FROM myCUR INTO decID, decName, decLocation;

CLOSE myCUR;
END
```

The actual error reporting is on this line, and mentions that the equals sign is not valid at that position.

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0;
```

There may be more issues than just this though, but the mySQL Workbench is not reporting those to me probably until this one is resolved.

Any ideas on how to get this stored procedure working?

Comment: You are uding ms sql server syntax, not mysql.

Comment: Which part is MSSQL? I'm fairly sure I can pull the core of this apart and run it fine from within mySQL Workbench. It's creating the cursor I am having trouble with, in wrapping that around the logic within the SP. https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/

Comment: From your link 'When working with MySQL cursor, you must also declare a NOT FOUND handler to handle the situation when the cursor could not find any row.' - mysql does not have @@FETCH_STATUS

Comment: Thanks P.Salmon, you are right. As soon as I fixed this up it all worked for me (Though i modified it some more to add the start/end of loop. I'll post my answer to close this one off once it lets me.

Comment: @Stephen85 @@FETCH_STATUS is ms sql server syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks as though I had a mix of syntax and as P.Salmon correctly pointed out, I was missing one crucial step of the guide I was following. Here is the working solution for reference.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `testTransfer` ()
BEGIN

DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE decID int;
DECLARE decName varchar(70);
DECLARE decLocation int;

DECLARE myCUR CURSOR FOR SELECT ID, userName, Location FROM usertable;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

OPEN myCUR;

processQueue: LOOP

FETCH NEXT FROM myCUR INTO decID, decName, decLocation;

IF finished = 1 THEN LEAVE processQueue;
END IF;

INSERT INTO users_log (ID, userName, Location)
VALUES (decID, decName, decLocation)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    ID = decID,
    userName = decName,
    Location = decLocation;

END LOOP processQueue;

CLOSE myCUR;

END
```